# Add sign (*) to values in a table that meet a condition (greater than) in an R Notebook

Tags: r

I would like to add a mark to values meeting a condition in an R Notebook. I could use knitr html tables, but a regular table would be as good.

The table summarises a result, and I would like to hightlight those that are greater than the confidence level (0.95) of the analysis. Getting the values in **bold** would be fine, of adding a '*' after the number can also work...

I've been trying... but I cannot manage to do it... except for looping (for loop) across all the cells and pasting the '*' if the condition is met. But there should be a better way!
Thanks!

An example:

```
example <- structure(list(Period = structure(1:3, .Label = c("period1", 
"period2", "period3", "period4", "period5", "period6", "period7"
), class = "factor"), Amphibians = c(1, 0.821782178217822, 0.891089108910891
), Aves = c(1, 0.811881188118812, 0.316831683168317)), .Names = c("Period", 
"Amphibians", "Aves"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to add a `*` to a `kable`. You'll need a numeric version to compare to 0.95 and a character version to paste the `*`. Also, factors are terrible for this sort of things.

```
example_temp <- apply(example,2,as.numeric)
example <- apply(example,2,as.character)
example <- as.data.frame(example,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

example[example_temp>.95&!is.na(example_temp)] <-paste(example[example_temp>.95&!is.na(example_temp)] ,"*")

kable(example)

|Period  |Amphibians  |Aves        |
|:-------|:-----------|:-----------|
|period1 |1.0000000 * |1.0000000 * |
|period2 |0.8217822   |0.8118812   |
|period3 |0.8910891   |0.3168317   |
```